# Deletion of User Profile

Tags: php, sql, laravel, foreign-keys, laravel-5

I'm trying to attempt to delete the user from my database as well as their profile. Right now it is only deleting the row in the users table. The only difference here is that the user_profiles table is marked as the user_id field which is NOT the increment field. How should this be accomplished? Is this something that should be wrapped in a transaction?

```
/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int $id id
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    $this->userRepository->delete($id);

    $this->userProfileRepository->delete($id);

    return redirect('users');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use transaction to make sure both records will be deleted but you could also create foreign key for `user_id` field in `user_profiles` table with `ON DELETE CASCADE` and it will be automatically removed so you don't need to run delete on `user_profiles` manually.

For example in your migration file it could look like:

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')>on('users')->onDelete('CASCADE');
```

Comment: What if there's a softDelete applied to the users and profiles. Does that matter?

Comment: @user3732216 I haven't tested it with soft deletes - if you use soft deletes only for users table it should work fine but if you want it use separately also in `user_profiles` you should test it but probably you will need to use transaction then to soft delete the user profile record

Comment: It does work but yes I tested it and had to ensure the user profiles model included soft deletes as well.